# Where is apps SQLite DB Stored on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to determine where on an android phone an apps SQLite database is stored. I am testings and need to be able to delete it and test the code for creation. On the simulator it is in /data/data/app package name/something.db but I am unable to find it on the actual phone. Does anybody know where it is stored and if it is accessable via DDMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If for whatever reason, you need to access the database on the phone, you must have root access (superuser in other words) on the phone. Then you will need a file explorer that uses root permission to give you access to the system files.

If all the above exists, then you will find the application database in:

**/data/data/com.yourpackage.name/databases.**

Comment: I see so it is just a permissions issue, but they are in the same place. Thanks

Comment: what type of questions your are posting . once refer android api and ask questions

Comment: Is that a duplicate `data` directory in your file path?

Comment: @JoshPinter: If you mean one of the two `/data/data...` then that's the default structure of the path.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Strange, my db path ended up being `/data/<package name>/databases/mydatabase.db`.

Comment: @JoshPinter: Interesting indeed. Just checked on my Nexus 4 and it's `/data/data` all right. _I think_ that works because you are accessing your own package from within your own app. Speculation of course. Will research more when I get a little free time on my hand. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele, you're probably bang on. Thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322762/293280), I was able to track down my application's DB file path using the following:

```
String DBPath = "//data//" + "<package name>" + "//databases//" + database_name;
```

JP