# Finding SQL Database File on Android Mobile Phone

Tags: android, sqlite, eclipse-adt

I've created an application that uses an Android SQL database. Is there any way to find this database on the Mobile Phone that the Application is installed to?

Essentially I want to then use an SQL Database Viewer to look at all the rows?

Answer (score 2):

`root/data/data/package/databases/database`

it should be in a file like that, in the emulator you can go straight to this using the file explorer in ddms, otherwise a rooted phone and ES file explorer

Comment: Note that here **package** means your app's package name. for example: *com.demo.andy*

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the emulator you can use the adb tool in the sdk-platform folder of the android install.

something like the following:

```
./adb shell
#sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.package/databases/database.db
```

you should then be able to do your queries.

If its on a phone, then try extract the database like above and use the sqlite3 tool to query that database.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4556642/450534

The same answer provided there is:

If for whatever reason, you need to access the database on the phone, you must have root access (superuser in other words) on the phone. Then you will need a file explorer that uses root permission to give you access to the system files.

If all the above exists, then you will find the application database in:

**/data/data/com.yourpackage.name/databases.**

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually own an android phone, would a normal user have these "superuser" privileges or do they have to get them from elsewhere?

Comment: A user will need to root his device to get superuser privileges. Google, by design, does not let users access to the system area of the device's installation. Combining SU with a file manager (with root explorer) will give the user this access.