# is it possible backup and RESTORE a database file in android? non root devices

Tags: java, android, sqlite, backup, restore

in my app I need get a backup of my database, 
but after I'll need restore it again,

i have read somethings, but i do not sure if this is necessary to have a rooted device,
i need backup/restore the all data in non root devices, is it possible?

my first idea was creating a txt file  for write the select, and later insert it again.

but i believe this is much "problem" then i don't know if this is possible copy the database and paste in sd card for backup, and copy from sd card and paste in path of database for restore for non root devices.

Comment: You can back up your database in a non rooted device with using the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883447/how-to-check-database-on-not-rooted-android-device/17883556#17883556

Comment: @TronicZomB does it work for restore too, for non rooted devices?

Comment: Not sure. You will have to try that out or keep searching.

Comment: Yes it works for both, just make sure you switch your variables where appropriate... I've used this code in my app

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is some code to make it work

```
private void importDB() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "<package name>"
                        + "//databases//" + "<database name>";
                String backupDBPath = "<backup db filename>"; // From SD directory.
                File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}

private void exportDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "<package name>"
                    + "//databases//" + "<db name>";
            String backupDBPath = "<destination>";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this worked for non-root devices :)

Comment: You could extract a method "copyDB" or something else instead of using the same code in both methods. This would increase modularity. In addition to that closing all opened Streams in finally blocks would be fine =)

Comment: Besides, getting the current db path via `getDatabasePath("<database name>")` should be more robust.

Comment: Not Working getting FileNotFoundException

Comment: I followed this, but getting "No such file or directory" while importing database, I get this while initializing the FileChannel for currentDBPath

Comment: In my case export/import successful but database showing older values not new one from imported database.