# How to backup & restore SqliteDatabase,SharedPreferences on SD-Card - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-backup-service

Hi i am developing an application in which i am storing the data to `Sqlite` & `SharedPrefrences`. I have studied from android docs they say we can do it by registering the service but i think this is only for Cloud storage where as i want to backup the data on SD card. I have also looked for FileBackHelper but it has not given any clarity.

Please tell which is the best way t implement it?

Comment: Best Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18322762/1318946

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy your sqlite db to sdcard like this

```
private void exportDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
       FileChannel source=null;
       FileChannel destination=null;
       String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.your.package" +"/databases/"+db_name;
       String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
       File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
       File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
       try {
            source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            source.close();
            destination.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Shared Preferences file location mostly chosen by device manufacture, so it is not good to hard code path of any shared preferences file.

Comment: thanks sir but how to restore it ?

Comment: just reverse the mechanism of `exportDB();`

Comment: ok thanks do i need to be the root of the device for copying db file .?

Comment: no. whereever you like. mostly people do that in sdcard

Comment: thank you.I guess the adnroid sqlite & sharedprefences path remains sam for all the devices.

Comment: no it does not. depends on device manufacturer

Comment: I am getting file not found exception /mnt/ sdcard open failed (EISDIR)

Comment: show your code and do you have read /write permission ?

Comment: yes i have read external storage permission. what to write in backupDBPath?

Comment: path where you want to save your exported db

Comment: why i am getting this error

Comment: you need to sort that out. I think you are not giving paths correctly